# Defining global variables for use in Functions

Tags: python, python-2.7, global

I'm having an issue with this simple counter program:

```
import time
counter = 0

def countup():
  while counter < 10:
      counter += 1
      print counter
      time.sleep (1);
  countdown();

def countdown():
  while counter > 0:
      counter -= 1
      print counter
      time.sleep (1);
  countup();

countup();
```

And the error I am getting is:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'counter' referenced before
>   assignment

Does this mean that I need to define a counter variable inside each function? I have tried this, but it didn't work. I also tried a global variable at the start using: `global counter = 0` but that didn't work either.

Apologies foor the noob question, I'm just a guy prodding a bit of python code.

Comment: Just use `global counter` at the top of the function body.

Comment: Even if you solve the global variable problem, your code has infinite recursion.

Comment: Yeah slider is correct this code is crazy. It'll never stop until you do it by CTRL+C

Comment: @slider sometimes you want code to run until it's stopped